# Question regarding existence of a commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Consider operators $A, B \, \& \, C$ which act on a vector space, and obey the following commutator relation.

$$[A, B] = 2C$$

Consider no restriction on their eigenvalue spectrum, i.e. the eigenvalues are unbounded. Given this operator relation holds, do there exist operators $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ such that their eigenvalues lie between $-1$ and $1$, i.e.

$$||A'||\leq 1,\quad ||B'||\leq 1, \quad ||C'|| \leq 1,$$

such that
$$A' = f_1(A), \quad B' = f_2(B), \quad C' = f_3(C)$$

and the following relation holds?

$$[A', B'] = 2 C'$$

Is there a convenient algorithm to generate these new operator relations from the given commutator structure in the first equation?

Comment: Does "no inital restriction on their eigenvalue spectrum" mean they can be unbounded?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes, that is what I meant. Otherwise I can scale them to obtain these relations. Thanks, I edited the same.

Comment: Unbounded operators cannot be defined on the whole space, and the domain of their commutator may be the null vector.

Comment: Do you mean they have a discrete ("eigenvalue") spectrum?